# Set Http headers for Angular to fix 401 REST API Authentication Error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this error 401 returning from API server (Authentication Error)

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong when passing the header?

```
  HEADER_ZENVIA: {
    "X-API-TOKEN": "xxx",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
```

**My Code:**

```
sendMessage(
    numeroDestino: string,
    nomeEmpresa: string,
    numeroVaga: string,
    nomeCliente: string,
    nomeRecrutadora: string
  ) {
    const contentsTemplate = {
      type: "template",
      templateId: this.templateID,
      fields: {
        nome_empresa: nomeEmpresa,
        numero_vaga: numeroVaga,
        nome_cliente: nomeCliente,
        nome_recrutadora: nomeRecrutadora,
      },
    };
    return this.http.post(`${API_ZENVIA_URL}`, {
      body: {
        from: BOT_NUMBER,
        to: `${numeroDestino}`,
        contents: [{ ...contentsTemplate }],
      },
      headers: { ...HEADER_ZENVIA },
    });
  }
```

**PostMan Works:**
[image: works]

Comment: Since it's a 401, it's most likely an issue with the API_TOKEN. Check your request headers, see if both your headers went through. Also check if your API token is still valid. Maybe it expired.

Comment: If you copy the network request as a Curl command and import it into postman does it work (or is that what your postman example is)?

Comment: I tryed with post man and works. The problem is not API_TOKEN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set headers for an http.post you should use the `HttpHeaders` class

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

// ...

const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .set('X-API-TOKEN', API_TOKEN);
const body = {
    from: BOT_NUMBER,
    to: `${numeroDestino}`,
    contents: [{ ...contentsTemplate }],
  }

     return this.http.post(API_ZENVIA_URL, body, { headers: headers })
```